# parallax web page just like presented link

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I want to design a website just like: [paris company intro page](http://www.paris.ir/home/) 
i tested some parallax libraries (for example: [Parallax Scrolling Effect](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect)) but it was not useful for this target. 
does it exist any library or software to build some pages just like it?

Comment: Try this one: http://www.jarallax.com/

Comment: @Andrew do yo think the website is writen by jarallax? can you suggest some oder tools?